# Import pictures into Powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, image, powerpoint

I have this excerpt of code to import picture into Powerpoint.

```
Fucnction InsertPic (gfilename as string)
activeWindow.selection.sliderange.shapes.addpicture(_FileName:=gfilename,_
LinkToFile:=msoFalse,_
SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Right: 40, Top: 25,_
Width:=70, Height:=40).Select
```

May I know how to edit this code to put the picture inside an already-opened PPT and the code can prompt user to select which picture to put in every slides (the same, one picture in every slides) except for the first and last slides, instead of me putting the address of the file?

Comment: what have you trued so far?

Comment: what do you mean>

Comment: what were your initial attempts. where do you have difficulty? do you encounter errors?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To select an already-opened PPT use the following code:

```
Dim ppt As Object
Set ppt = GetObject(, "powerpoint.application")
```

To prompt user to pick up certain image use

```
Dim sl As Object
dim gfilename as String

For Each sl In ppt.activepresentation.slides
  FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (FileFilter:="Pictures, *.jpg; *.gif", Title:="Select a Picture",   MultiSelect:=False)
   sl.Shapes.AddPicture FileName, 0, -1, 25, 40, 10, 40
Next sl
```

and finally, to omnit the first and the last slide, add condition

```
If sl.slidenumber > 1 And sl.slidenumber < ppt.activepresentation.slides.Count Then
```

Wrapping up:

```
Function InsertPic()
Dim ppt As Object
Dim sl As Object
Dim FileName As String

Set ppt = GetObject(, "powerpoint.application")
For Each sl In ppt.activepresentation.slides
  If sl.slidenumber > 1 And sl.slidenumber < ppt.activepresentation.slides.Count Then
    FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (FileFilter:="Pictures, *.jpg; *.gif", Title:="Select a Picture", MultiSelect:=False)
    sl.Shapes.AddPicture FileName, 0, -1, 25, 40, 10, 40
  End If
Next sl


End Function
```